# It is possible to use LLVM Bytecode as Z3 input?

Tags: llvm, z3

I have a description in LLVM bytecode and I need to pass as Z3 input. If it can be done, how is it done?? If not, is there any tool that will do it??

Comment: LLVM IR describes procedural programs. Z3 proves theorems. These two things are not obviously isomorphic, so you'll have to give some more detail about what you're trying to do. Are you trying to prove something about a program (given in LLVM IR)? Are you trying to encode a theorem/proof in LLVM IR?

Comment: I've got part of a program in LLVM bytecode that need to be proved in Z3.

Comment: You may be using Z3 terminology I'm not familiar with, but I'm gonna go out on a limb and claim that doesn't make sense: A program is not a theorem. Do you want to prove some property of/statement about the program? If so, which one?

Answer (score 5):

Two tools that can translate from C code to a form Z3 can handle:

1) SMACK (https://github.com/smackers/smack)

This translates annotated C code to the Boogie language, using LLVM bitcode as an intermediate representation. The Boogie tool (http://boogie.codeplex.com) can then be used to generate verification conditions that can be checked by Z3. Manual annotation of the code can be a demanding task, however. In particular, you have to write inductive invariants for all the loops and pre/post conditions for your C functions sufficient to prove that your program satisfies its specification.

2) UFO (https://bitbucket.org/arieg/ufo/wiki/Home)

This tool can translate from C to SMT-LIB Horn logic, again by way of LLVM bitcode. The results can be checked by one of Z3's fixedpoint engines. In this approach you don't have to manually annotate the loops and procedures (since Z3 discovers these annotations by itself) but the capacity of the tool is far less.

Answer (score 3):

The question isn't totally well-posed or clear, but maybe check out the SMACK tool (https://github.com/smackers/smack/wiki), which compiles C programs (with assertions) using LLVM's clang and uses Boogie's intermediate representation (https://boogie.codeplex.com/) so you can query Z3 about the assertions in the program.

If that doesn't do directly what you need, the source is available, so you can see how it converts the assertions and LLVM bitcode files to Boogie's intermediate representation.

Answer (score 2):

[PAGAI](http://pagai.forge.imag.fr/) performs static analysis on LLVM bitcode. It automatically computes loop invariants and checks for the reachability of some failure conditions (like UFO); you can use assertions and assumptions. One thing it does internally is to turn loop-free programs in LLVM bitcode into SMT formulas representing their semantics.